# How to avoid autorotation in iOS 8 from Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios8, autorotate

I am using Xcode and after updating to iOS 8, the `shouldAutorotate` function doesn't work.
I don't want my `viewcontroller` to autorotate.

How can I restrict autorotation in iOS 8 from Xcode?

Comment: You couldn't have googled this ... You just choose which orientations you want to support in your targets > general setting.

Comment: @CW0007007 You seem to infer that the OP wants to restrict autorotation in **all** cases.

Comment: @Maple you seem to infer that they don't.

Comment: you can choose the orientation you want, but once chosen you can not rotate, that´s what I need...

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1. First, in info.plist select the orientations which your application supports. Meaning if your application only displays in portrait mode then select portrait as your only setting.

   [image]

   If you want to restrict this orientation from appdelegate you can add this code

   ```
   - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
       NSUInteger orientations;

       UIViewController* presented = [[[[NavigationManager sharedManager ] navigationController] viewControllers] lastObject];
       orientations = [presented supportedInterfaceOrientations];

       return orientations;
   }
   ```
2. Make common class for UIViewcontroller and add these methods:

   BaseViewController.h

   ```
   @interface BaseViewController : UIViewController{
   }
   ```

   BaseViewController.m

   ```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
   {
       return NO;
   }

   - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
   {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in Navigation controller class

---

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

return NO;    
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientation

{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

}
```

---